# What are the dangers of using OpenID for your website?

Tags: openid

Let's say I create a website like StackOverFlow and decide to use OpenID. What's to prevent me, or anyone else for that matter, from phishing the ID's? That is, how can you truly know that any website is using OpenID and not pretending to? And how do you protect myself against this?

Expanding on this, let's say one site did compromise your openID credentials, couldn't they use it on every other site using openID (a global password hack)? Wouldn't then the security of your openID then only be as strong as the weakest website/provider?

Comment: What harm is there in letting your OpenID loose? You still need to verify your identity at the OpenID provider before any harm can be done.

Comment: You should probably edit either headline or text. I understand the headline as asking for dangers of using OpenID as a developer (like SO), but the text is about risks from the user's perspective.

Comment: What is your question?  OpenID URIs are public.  Mine is http://www.aaronhockley.com - there's nothing to phish.  The authentication of the OpenID provider, not the relying party.

Comment: @Mark: Exactly. But how do you know say StackOverFlow is properly verifying your ID and not just pretending to?

Comment: @phihag: My thinking is the security to my website is only as good as the open provider used. Actually, more importantly, my security is only as secure as the users skills. For example if they go to a website that fakes the provider and enter in their credentials, my site is also compromised.

Comment: @ahockley: Let's pretend StackOverFlow pretended to use openID. And Jeff faked all the credential gathering pages, made you think you were being properly validated. Couldn't he compromise your credentials then? And then my site would only be as safe as all the sites you visited...

Comment: @Stephanie That's a problem with providers that use weak credential system such as a standard username/password, not with OpenID itself.  Providers such as Vidoop, myOpenID, and Verisign's PIP allow for better security.

Comment: @ahockley: Which means your website's security is only as good as the worse provider.

Answer (score 8):

All you enter is the ID, no password. The ID is public, therefore "phishing" it is not a security hole. Some providers even use the same ID for all users, for instance the ID for a google account is always `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#Logging_in) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 7):

For users who know very little about how OpenID works, you could create a few spoof pages that look like the websites their OpenID is for (like, say, any of the free email providers that handle OpenID).  If they forget to check the domain they're on before filling in their username and password, then evildomain now has their OpenID username and password.

On the server side, you're relying on external sites for identity verification.  So, if there turns out to be a hole in provider XYZ's OpenID authentication form that lets the password "swordfish" work on any account, anyone can impersonate users from that provider anywhere that accepts OpenID.

allesklar made a good point while I was typing this that segues nicely to my last point: If you mix local and remote users, you suddenly need two ban lists instead of one; the second ban list for "bad" OpenID providers set up by people to create batches of accounts... or ones that automatically authorize any account name given to them.

Comment: In your comment: "... you could create a few spoof pages that look like the websites their OpenIDs is for)." Isn't that exactly what would happen? If it goes mainstream, most people won't have a clue what's legit and what's not. Even today most people dont' really understand SSL certs...

Answer (score 6):

When someone puts in an open ID at your site, you authenticate the user by asking the site where the user's OpenID lives (and only that site) if this user is okay.  AOL can't validate a Yahoo OpenID, for example.

If the user is not already authenticated at that site, authentication fails and you need to redirect to that site's login page. A real authentication still needs to happen, but it always happens with the OpenID provider for that user. As a user, you are protected because you should only ever see the login page you are familiar with. A malicious site will have a hard time siphoning OpenID credentials, because users never give those sites their passwords directly.

Once the user is authenticated with their provider (or if they are from the get-go), the provider will report this to your web site. What changes for OpenID is that your site now needs to trust certain other sites- that they will accurately report status for their users.

Someone could set up a "malicious" open id provider, and try to skim off new ids that way, but that's between a user and the provider. Since this authentication is all about reputation, the idea is that such a provider wouldn't stay in business for long. If nothing else, sites could blacklist those providers. A malicious provider would not be able to impersonate open ids that are registered with other providers.

Another possibility for a malicious provider is to set up an OpenID service that simply always confirms any id passed to it for authentication (or allows an administrator to setup a back door for it's users).  However, that would only effect users that registered with that provider. Again, sites could blacklist these providers, and as they bank on reputation the idea that wouldn't stay in business long still holds.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenID sytem is very secure and gaining a lot of ground because of it.

The main downside I see is that if the OpenID provider of many of your users goes under, these users will be locked out of your site. Hence you should have a username/password backup plan, store their email address after validating it so that you can send them a password in case of emergency/catastrophe.

Comment: or at least an email, so the site can send you a link for a new signup

Comment: ...or let people assign multiple OpenIDs to their account, so if one goes down, there's still another one they can use.

Answer (score 1):

Funny story. I found an exploit on SO that allowed me to change someone's profile entirely. If Jeff'd been using email+password, I could have owned his account, but because SO uses OpenID, there was nothing to do but change his Gavitar to something funny.

The bug in question was reported, fixed, and I'm still waiting on my Hacker badge. :P

Answer (score 1):

The key here that scares me is just not owned his account on one website, but every website that uses openID!!!

Comment: In order to own his openID account, I'd need to own his openID provider, which, depending on who it is, may be a quite difficult task.

It's also worth noting that most people use the same email+password combo on many websites. It've been about the same end result had I gotten his credentials here.

Comment: Couldn't you just put up a fake website that pretended to validate against this provider. Then you'd own his information...

Comment: Please setup a website where you think you can convince me that it's the actual myVidoop site.  Hint: they don't use a usual username/password for authentication.

Comment: First you'd have to put up the fake site, then convince StackOverlfow to go to that fake site instead of the real one, and then convince the user to ignore the fact that normally their browser fills in the userid and password and fill them in manually...